# Determine the expected value of the after $n$ periods.

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $S(0)$ be the initial price of the stock. Assume that in each period the stock can go either up by a factor of $u$ or down by a factor of $d$. Assume that the probability that the stock goes up is $p$ and the probability that it goes down is $1−p$ in each period, and that these events are independent. Determine the expected value of the stock after $n$ periods.

(Express your answer in closed form in terms of $u$, $d$, $p$, $n$).

I know how to find the expected value of the stock after one period, it would be: $$E[S(T)]=[S(0)(1+u) \times p] + [S(0)(1-d) \times (1-p)]$$

But I don't know how to find the expectation for $n$ periods.
Since they are independent is this correct?
$$E[S(T)]=\frac{([S(0)(1+u) \times p] + [S(0)(1-d) \times (1-p)])^n}{n}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E[S_0,n]$ be the expected value after $n$ periods, starting from $S_0$.  Since each price change is multiplicative we see that $$E[\lambda S_0,n]=\lambda E[S_0,n]$$

Now, looking at the first period we see the recursion:  $$E[S_0,n]=p\times E[S_0(1+u),n-1]+(1-p)\times E[S_0(1-d),n-1]$$$$=(1+pu -(1-p)d)\times E[S_0,n-1]$$  Iterating shows that $$E[S_0,n]=(1+pu -(1-p)d)^n\times S_0$$

Sanity Check:  if $u=d$ and $p=\frac 12$ then symmetry tells us that the expected value must always be $S_0$, no matter how many periods there are, and this is indeed implied by the formula.

Comment: Why doesn't $p\times E[S_0(1+u),n-1]+(1-p)\times E[S_0(1-d),n-1]$ become $S(0)(1+pu-(1-p)d)$? I thought the expected value of $[S_0(1+u),n-1]$ and $[S_0(1-d),n-1]$ is $[S(0)(p+pu)+S(0)(1-p-d+dp)]$ then after factoring out the $S(0)$ I got the same thing that you did except with an $S(0)$ in front?

Comment: Your formula has no $n$ in it...that doesn't make sense.  Suppose $p=1$, so you only go up.  Then the answer is clearly $(1+u)^nS_0$, as predicted by my formula.